# Filter according to select option

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-filter

I am developing simple ionic app which have a table showing Mobile phones models and i have drop down list to filter the table according to selected option i made it like this but i do not why i does not work.

```
 <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon">
            </i>
            <input ng-model="searchValue" placeholder="Search" type="text">
            </input>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
                brand
            </div>
            <select ng-model="chosenBrand">
                <option>
                    Nokia
                </option>
                <option selected="">
                    Samsung
                </option>
                <option>
                    Apple
                </option>
                <option>
                    Sony
                </option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="col table-colmun">
            <h5>
                Brand
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col table-colmun">
            <h5>
                Model
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col table-colmun">
            <h5>
                Year
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="mobile in mobilesArray |filter:chosenBrand" ng-click="selectItem(mobile, $index)" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}">
        <div class="col table-colmun">
            {{mobile.brand}}
        </div>
        <div class="col table-colmun">
            {{mobile.model}}
        </div>
        <div class="col table-colmun">
            {{mobile.year}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

when i select an option it gives me a blank table with now data at all however when i write {{chosenBrand}} in the view it shows the selected option.

Comment: Your options need to have value to work, like `<option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>`

Answer (score 1):

As rightly pointed out, You need to have a value for the options.

Also instead of manually using these options you can use the [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive.

<s>like this `<select ng-options="brand.brandName for brand in brands" ng-model="chosenBrand"></select>`</s>

with a brand array like

```
[
    {brandId:1,brandName:'Nokia'},
    {brandId:2,brandName:'Apple'},   
    {brandId:3,brandName:'Samsung'},
    {brandId:4,brandName:'Sony'},       
]
```

---EDIT--- 
**So when using ng-options if you fon't use as the options have values 1,2,3 and so on. instead use this**

`<select ng-options="brand.brandName as brand.brandName for brand in brands" ng-model="chosenBrand"></select>`

Check [out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/)

Comment: but when apply the filter when using ng-options it has the same problem!

Comment: @MohamedA.Shebl You have to use `as` in the ng-options directive. Edited the answer for it. Hope this helps.